# How to scrape data on a subpage of a website?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

Here's the website : [website](https://www.booking.com/hotel/fr/d-argentine.fr.html?label=gen173nr-1DEgdyZXZpZXdzKIICOOgHSDNYBGhNiAEBmAENuAEXyAEM2AED6AEBiAIBqAIDuAKr2vuGBsACAdICJDE1YjBlZDY1LTI2NzEtNGM3Mi04OWQ1LWE5MjQ3OWFmNzE2NtgCBOACAQ;sid=303509179a2849df63e4d1e5bc1ab1e3;dest_id=-1456928;dest_type=city;dist=0;group_adults=2;group_children=0;hapos=1;hpos=1;no_rooms=1;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;sr_order=popularity;srepoch=1625222475;srpvid=48244b2523010057;type=total;ucfs=1&#tab-main%27)

And here's my script :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait     
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By     
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#chemin du folder ou vous avez placer votre chromedriver
PATH = "driver\chromedriver.exe"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1200,900")
options.add_argument('enable-logging')

#driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=PATH)


url = 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/fr/d-argentine.fr.html?label=gen173nr-1DEgdyZXZpZXdzKIICOOgHSDNYBGhNiAEBmAENuAEXyAEM2AED6AEBiAIBqAIDuAKr2vuGBsACAdICJDE1YjBlZDY1LTI2NzEtNGM3Mi04OWQ1LWE5MjQ3OWFmNzE2NtgCBOACAQ;sid=303509179a2849df63e4d1e5bc1ab1e3;dest_id=-1456928;dest_type=city;dist=0;group_adults=2;group_children=0;hapos=1;hpos=1;no_rooms=1;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;sr_order=popularity;srepoch=1625222475;srpvid=48244b2523010057;type=total;ucfs=1&#tab-main'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=PATH)

driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)

headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'}

cookie = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]')
try:
    cookie.click()
except:
    pass

time.sleep(2)

country = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="hp_nav_reviews_link toggle_review track_review_link_zh"]')
country.click()
time.sleep(2)

url2 = driver.current_url

commspos = []
commsneg = []
header = []
notes = []
dates = []
datestostay = []


results = requests.get(url2, headers = headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

reviews = soup.find_all('li', class_ = "review_item clearfix")

for review in reviews:
    try:
        commpos  = review.find("p", class_  = "review_pos").text.strip()
    except:
        commpos = 'NA'

    commspos.append(commpos)



    try:
        commneg  = review.find("p", class_  = "review_neg").text.strip()
    except:
        commneg = 'NA'

    commsneg.append(commneg)


    head = review.find('div', class_ = 'review_item_header_content').text.strip()
    header.append(head)


    note = review.find('span', class_ = 'review-score-badge').text.strip()
    notes.append(note)


    date = review.find('p', class_ = 'review_item_date').text[23:].strip()
    dates.append(date)


    try:
        datestay = review.find('p', class_ = 'review_staydate').text[20:].strip()
        datestostay.append(datestay)
    except:
        datestostay.append('NaN')





data = pd.DataFrame({
    'commspos' : commspos,
    'commsneg' : commsneg,
    'headers' : header,
    'notes' : notes,
    'dates' : dates,
    'datestostay' : datestostay,
    })


data.to_csv('dftest.csv', sep=';', index=False, encoding = 'utf_8_sig')
```

My script goes here : [image: subpage]

But my csv file as output is empty. I  assume it has to do with some kind of javascript. I already encounter that, the script goes to the subpage but isn't really into the subpage, hence doesn't have access to the html part and give nothing in the output.

Answer (score 0):

That sub-page that you want loads the data from this URL.

https://www.booking.com/hotelfeaturedreviews/fr/d-argentine.fr.html?label=gen173nr-1DEgdyZXZpZXdzKIICOOgHSDNYBGhNiAEBmAENuAEXyAEM2AED6AEBiAIBqAIDuAKr2vuGBsACAdICJDE1YjBlZDY1LTI2NzEtNGM3Mi04OWQ1LWE5MjQ3OWFmNzE2NtgCBOACAQ;sid=22417257c7da25395d270bcc7c6ec2e8;dest_id=-1456928;dest_type=city;group_adults=2;group_children=0;hapos=1;hpos=1;no_rooms=1;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;sr_order=popularity;srepoch=1625222475;srpvid=48244b2523010057;type=total;ucfs=1&&_=1625476042625

You can easily scrape this page and extract the data you need.

Comment: Thanks but how do you have access to this URL ? Because I want to run this script to multiple hotels. This is just the first part.

Comment: I allow myself to ask you again. How did you had this URL ? :) Because I want to run this script to multiple hotels. The script above is just the first part

Comment: You can see the URL using Chrome Dev Tools. -> Network Tab when loading the page. This Tab will have all the links that the site requests.

Comment: Also you can see that the parameters in your main URL and in this URL are same. You can do a bit of analysis and use this URL for all hotels.

Comment: I just saw that but the URL doesn't contains all the comments.. just a few, like 20 instead of 1100. Do you know how to go to the next pages of the comments with your url ?

Comment: There is no button to go to the next page like in the subpage so I'm quite lost.